# Something that is not a problem until it becomes a problem

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

I am wondering if there is a word or phrase encompassing the concept for something that is not a problem, until it becomes a problem.

Example:

- Hiring a spouse to work for your company is not a problem, until someone doesn't like them (making it a problem).
- Politicians taking money from individuals is not a problem, until they take money from the "wrong" people (making it a problem).
- Copying someone's work is not a problem in and of itself, until the person is affected.

The most relevant concepts that I can think of :

- Conflicts of interest
- Plagiarism

Comment: Please could you give an example of the way in which the word you are seeking might be used?

Comment: ***Risks***, did you mean?

Comment: It's *asking for trouble*.

Comment: @Drew I think "asking for trouble" is what I was going for, can you post as an answer?

Comment: I would, but someone will complain that I don't have a reference for it. I'm not sure where to find a reference for a phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking to the plagiarizer, or the nepotist, for example, here are some ways you can explain potential future difficulties:

- You are *asking for trouble*.  [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ask+for+trouble) (crediting Drew in the comment)
- This could easily *blow up in your face*.
- Imagine what this would look like in a headline.

Answer (score 3):

a **"potential"** or **"latent"** problem**

> - **potential** -  "capable of being but not yet in existence" -  [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/potential)
> - **latent** - "present or potential but not evident or active" - [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latent)

Examples in the literature:

- [**1.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=fk45iKPUmjUC&pg=PA197&dq=%22a+potential+problem%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5w4iO__3OAhVBiJAKHSR-AR04ChDoAQhWMAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20potential%20problem%22&f=false) -  "Is the fact that the research is done at two different schools **a potential problem** with the study?"
- [**2.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=yWRluqbugioC&q=%22potential+problems%22&dq=%22potential+problems%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYvpre__3OAhUCvJAKHYn5AmMQ6AEISzAG)  - "**Potential problems** related to weightlessness and artificial gravity..."
- [**3.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=uPaxCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22latent+problems%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz7qKggP7OAhUGG5AKHQg_B_sQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22latent%20problems%22&f=false) - "**Latent problems** weren't directly visible to a technician but might occur in the future."
- [**4.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wI6fLAPpdDgC&pg=PA216&dq=%22a+potential+problem%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr2re7_v3OAhWIgpAKHVisAGQQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20potential%20problem%22&f=false) - "An example of **a potential problem** for a couple expecting a baby who already have a two-year old child might be jealousy on the part of the toddler after the baby is born."

Answer (score 1):

***A hostage to fortune***, perhaps?

*To give hostage to fortune* - To take an action or make a statement that is risky because it could cause you trouble later.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2010_July_6